# Text box at the end of data of Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to enter a simple text box in Excel sheet:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizon‌​tal, 60, 1, 1, 60).Select
```

But I want its position to be automatically at the end of data of Excel sheet. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shape of your data range and where exactly you want the text box. Here's an example with data range in column A.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, rng.Height, 22, 22).Select
```

The rang has also a width property so you can use it as well.

The result of the above code:
[image]